# Call to undefined method Poll::updatePoll()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a site poll but I'm getting this error:

> Call to undefined method Poll::updatePoll() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\poll\controllers\poll.php on line 10

I have checked my class definition and the method. Everything seems to be fine, but the error keeps appearing. This is the code in my model:

```
<?php

class Poll {

    private $db;

    //method requires a database connection as argument
    public function __construct( $dbConnection ) {
        //store the received conection in the $this->db property\
        $this->db = $dbConnection;  
    }

    public function updatePoll( $input ) {
        if ( $input==='yes') {
            $updateSQL = "UPDATE poll SET yes = yes + 1 WHERE poll_id = 1";
        } else if ( $input === 'no') {
            $updateSQL = "UPDATE poll SET no = no + 1 WHERE poll_id = 1";
        }
        $updateStatement = $this->db->prepare($updateSQL);
        $updateStatement->execute();
    }

    public function getPollData() {
        //The actual SQL statement 
        $sql = "SELECT poll_question, yes, no FROM poll WHERE poll_id = 1";
        //Use the PDO connection to create a PDOStatement object
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        //tell MySQL to execute the statement
        $statement->execute();
        //retrieve the first row of data from the table
        $pollData = $statement->fetchObject();
        //make poll data available to the caller    
        return $pollData;
    }
}
```

The code in my controller is as follows:

```
<?php
    include_once "models/poll.class.php";

    $poll = new Poll( $db );
    //check if the poll is submitted 
    $isPollSubmitted = isset($_POST['user-input']);
    if ( $isPollSubmitted ) {
        $input = $_POST['user-input'];
        $poll->updatePoll($input);
    }

    $pollData = $poll->getPollData();
    $pollView = include_once "views/poll-html.php";
    return $pollView;

?>
```

This is the code in my index file. I suspect $db (database connection) might be problem

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    //load model
    include_once "models/Page_Data.class.php";
    $PageData = new Page_Data;
    $PageData->title = "PHP/MySQL site poll example";

    $PageData->content = include_once "controllers/poll.php";


    //database credentials
    $dbInfo = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=playground";
    $dbUser = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";

    $db = new PDO( $dbInfo, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $page = include_once "views/page.php";
    //output generated page
    echo $page; 


?>
```

Comment: is `$db` defined when called in the `Poll` constructor?

Comment: i didnt get an error regarding that, so i assume its fine. Could it be why it says the method is undefined?

Comment: i have just included my index file containing the database connection code

Comment: `poll.php on line 10` - What line is that?

Comment: $poll->updatePoll( $input ); its in my controller

Comment: I'm confused by the structure and what is going on here ( or what file is what ) but if `poll.php` is either IN or IS the `controller` then the database connection comes afterwards according to the flow of your `index` ... ??

Comment: The model is poll.class.php (the first file), which is included in the controller poll.php. The database connection is made in the index file. In poll.class.php i created a constructor to share the database connection from the index file with the model, i.e poll.class.php